# Patching RavenDB when field already exists

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb, nosql

I am working with RavenDB in c# and I added a new field to an existing model. I am using this command`

> PatchCommandType.Set

` to add the new field to existing documents.

When this patch command runs on documents that already have this specific field set, will the patch command override the existing field/value or will it create a duplicate field with the same name?

I would like to leave this patch command code in as we move forward with the development and want to make sure it will not corrupt the database.

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Index", 
        new IndexQuery{
            Query = "Model:"
        }, 
        new []{
            new PatchRequest{
                Type = PatchCommandType.Set,
                Name = "IsArchived",
                Value = true
            },
        }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set will create the field if it isn't there, or modify it if it exists, yes.

Comment: Okay, so I looked up some documentation and saw there is an add method and I was wondering if that would only add the field if it didn't exist. All the documentation example says is "add new property".

Comment: Add is there to add an item to an array. See the XML comments here: https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/v3.5/Raven.Abstractions/Data/PatchCommandType.cs